# conditional join with mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql, conditional-statements

I have 3 tables:

```
ONE (ID - TYPE)

TWO (ID - FIELDa)

THREE (ID - FIELDb)
```

If `ONE.TYPE = 0` I would have a join of `ONE` with `TWO`, else if `ONE.TYPE = 1` a join with `THREE`.

How can I do a single join select query with all the record?

result:

```
TYPE - RESULT (FIELDa or FIELDb)
```

I write this:

```
SELECT `m`.`meal_name`,
                        `m`.`short`,
                        `m`.`id`,
                        `m`.`time`,
                        `m`.`budget`,
                        `p`.`filename`,
                        `t`.`type`,

        CASE `m`.`author_type`
       WHEN 0 THEN `a`.`author`
       WHEN 1 THEN `u`.`first_name`
       ELSE NULL
       END AS autore

FROM                    
                        `photos` p,
                        `types` t,
                        `meals` m                      
LEFT JOIN `authors` a
              ON  `m`.`author_type`=0 AND (`m`.`id` = `a`.`id` )
LEFT JOIN `users` u         
              ON `m`.`author_type`=1 AND (`m`.`id` = `u`.`user_id`  )

WHERE 
    `m`.`type` = `t`.`id`
    AND
    `m`.`id` = `p`.`id`
```

But it return only some record with author_type = 0 ....any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want your result set to look like? What columns do you need in the end?

Comment: Why not break it up into two separate queries?
1. Query database for `ONE.TYPE`
2. Use result to build query (based on value of result, use query with appropriate `JOINS`)

Comment: You have a `WHERE` keyword here, where it should be `AND`.  `ON m.author_type=0 WHERE (m.id = u.user_id  )`

Comment: the new error is because you aliased `authors` as `a`. Use `m.id = a.id`

Comment: i made the query but there are some problem

Comment: @michele You need to start with _only_ the parts your question was originally about, and incorporate my answer. That will return both `author_type`. Then incrementally, add the other remaining joins. I suspect you aren't seeing the full result now because you are joining two other tables implicitly (comma-separated FROM clause) which become `INNER JOIN`s.  Those `INNER JOIN`s might eliminate other rows from the final result.

Comment: Convert those to explicit joins and make them `LEFT JOIN`:  `FROM meals m LEFT JOIN photos p ON m.id = p.id LEFT JOIN type t ON m.type = t.id` followed by the other conditional `LEFT JOIN`s specified in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what columns you are matching on for the JOIN.

Here's an example of one way to do a "conditional" join:

```
SELECT one.id
     , one.type
     , CASE one.type
       WHEN 0 THEN two.field
       WHEN 1 THEN tee.field
       ELSE NULL
       END AS field
  FROM one
  LEFT 
  JOIN two
    ON one.type = 0
   AND two.id = one.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN three tee
    ON one.type = 1
   AND tee.id = one.id
```

To restrict the resultset to only rows only that had a "match", we'd add

```
WHERE two.id IS NOT NULL
   OR tee.id IS NOT NULL
```

---

**UPDATED ANSWER (BASED ON UPDATED QUESTION)**

The two most likely explanation for "only some rows" are

1) the JOIN predicates in your query are filtering out rows which don't find a match in another table

2) the JOIN predicates are specified on columns that don't "match" (for example, the `users.user_id` column matching to `meals.id` column strikes us a bit odd.)

If you want to return ALL rows from `meals`, whether or not there are matching rows in any of the other tables (`photos` or `types`), then use OUTER JOIN operations, with `meals` as the driving table.

For example:

```
 SELECT m.meal_name
      , m.short
      , m.id
      , m.time
      , m.budget
      , p.filename
      , t.type
      , CASE m.author_type
        WHEN 0 THEN a.author
        WHEN 1 THEN u.first_name
        ELSE NULL
        END AS autore
  FROM meals m
  LEFT
  JOIN types t
       ON t.id = m.type
  LEFT
  JOIN photos p
       ON p.id = m.id
  LEFT
  JOIN authors a
       ON m.author_type=0 
       AND m.id = a.id
  LEFT
  JOIN users u
       ON m.author_type=1
       AND m.id = u.user_id
```

Note that we prefer to avoid the old-school comma syntax for the join operation. We prefer to use the `JOIN` keyword in place of the comma, and we prefer the JOIN predicates to be in the `ON` clause, rather than the `WHERE` clause.

The query above will return EVERY row from meals, along with the matching rows from each of the tables.

And again, the join predicates strike us as a being a bit odd. For example, the `id` column from `meals` matching the `user_id` column from `users` seems a bit strange. Normally, we see the match done on between a foreign key in one table to a primary key in another table. (But we don't see the table schema, or any sample data, so this may be valid. It just looks odd.)

Answer (score 1):

You may perform two `LEFT JOIN`s with the appropriate condition of `ONE.TYPE` in each, and in the final `SELECT` list, use `COALESCE()` to select between the non-null value returned by the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  ONE.ID,
  TYPE,
  /* The LEFT JOINs will return NULL for one of these. 
     Use COALESCE() to get the non-null result
     If neither matches, NULL is returned
   */
  COALESCE(TWO.Fielda, THREE.FIELDb) AS RESULT
FROM
  ONE
  LEFT JOIN TWO ON (ONE.TYPE = 0 AND ONE.ID = TWO.ID)
  LEFT JOIN THREE ON (ONE.TYPE = 1 AND ONE.ID = THREE.ID)
```

#### Incorporating the full query you added:

You should not mix implicit joins with explicit joins, and indeed you should not really use the old style implicit joins at all (comma-separated tables in the `FROM` clause). Convert those to explicit `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
SELECT `m`.`meal_name`,
                    `m`.`short`,
                    `m`.`id`,
                    `m`.`time`,
                    `m`.`budget`,
                    `p`.`filename`,
                    `t`.`type`,
                    COALESCE(a.author, u.firstname) AS autore
FROM
    /* Replace all the implicit joins */
    meals m 
    LEFT JOIN photos p ON m.id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN type t ON m.t
    LEFT JOIN `authors` a
              ON  `m`.`author_type`=0 AND (`m`.`id` = `a`.`id` )
    LEFT JOIN `users` u         
              ON `m`.`author_type`=1 AND (`m`.`id` = `u`.`user_id`  )ype = t.id
/* No WHERE clause join conditions remain, they are in the ON
   clauses instead...*/
```

Comment: Isn't this assuming that you will only get results from one table? What if the `ID` is present in both?

Comment: @A.O. Am I wrong in the logic that if ID is present in both, it implies that both `TYPE` values are also present? There is no aggregation here, so both rows would be returned and the OP has asked for the a selector between the columns.

Comment: ahhh it appears you are correct. I was just trying to avoid the `COALESCE` returning the first result in the case that there were two non-null values returned, and OP thinking the first result was actually the only non-null value.... +1